# Delphi: Lost Icon in top left corner

Tags: delphi, icons

Something very strange happened and I have no idea why.  I've lost the icon in the top left corner for my Delphi 7 application.   The icon still shows up attached to the executable in windows.  But on the task bar and the top left corner, it's got the default Application box (for winXP Blue bar on top with white box)

Any idea what kind of a thing might cause such a thing?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: You have code like
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, 0);
<g&d>

Comment: Sorry about not putting a screenshot up, I don't think it'd help too much.  The problem seems to have resolved itself, not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your app's project resource using delphi's Image Editor.
make sure you have {$R *.res} in your .dpr file.

Answer (score 5):

As X-Ray told you make sure {$R *.res} is in the project source (Project / View Source) - just before "begin". If it's already there, try to re-set the application ICO (Project / Options) and/or main form icon (From1.Icon) and then "Build all projects" to see if it helps.

Also be sure to use a valid Windows Icon.

Comment: It's kind of strange because I was using compiler directives to specify unique icons for different builds of our product.  It was working A-Ok until yesterday.  I tried changing it back to {$R *.res} and that did work, then I changed to back and it didn't work, then I fixed something else which was causing an access violation in the finalization part of some code I don't think I wrote and that fixed it.  Yet another Delphi mystery left unsolved.